# Render is either all white or all gray

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

These are a few images of my scene. 
I added lights, camera and rendered image. It turned out to be all white.

This first image is my entire scene with camera and light setup.

[image]

Second is the camera view render.

[image]

Third is the camera view of the scene.

[image]

[this is the link for images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2PDt.jpg)

Let me know if I need to add more images.

Here is my .blend file.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! Is your camera really positioned where you think it is? Nothing obstructing it? Hard to guess from just screen shots. If you can [post a .blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) it will be easier for us to answer.

Comment: my camera is positioned correctly sir...how do i post .blend

Comment: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I uploaded the file  can u please telll me what am i doing wrong ,,Thank you

Comment: where's the link to your blend? are you rendering on gpu? what gpu do you have? what are your world settings?

Comment: i uploaded my .blend to the link blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com, i have nvidia 560 cu II, can you please tell me other site where i can upload my blend file

Comment: @Psytrancemute you need to post the link to your file. Once you upload in blendexchange you'll get a link. Edit your question and add such link so someone else can download it. Read the help section of the site to learn how to use it: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help/

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/Xty46 i am dealing with some bug here is zip file https://www.mediafire.com/?q6ziuvd3o8hrzi6 i will also add it to the post ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've downloaded your blend file and the answer is what Mentalist already suspected: Your camera is looking straight at a wall. If you want to leave the camera where it is you could increase the clipping start value of your camera from .1 to 1. Otherwise you have to move the camera to the inside of the wall, if you want to render what's inside.

Comment: Yea camera is not on place at that one because ,because the time i uploaded the file was experimenting on camera ,but now that you have the files u can try to take camera  inside the area and take render then tell me if its working or not

Comment: it is working...